# Phpmyadmin feed a timestamp column with "0000-00-00 00:00:00"?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

in PhpMyAdmin (OVH Mutu), a table with column type timestamp.
Impossible to put into this colum a timestamp : 
Always display datetime like 2017-01-09 23:02:01 !!!
It generate several problmes : default current_timestamp give in this table "0000-00-00 00:00:00". Calculate delays is impossible.
The only way : define a int(11) type column.
An idea ?...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to calculate with the timestamp field, you simply may use `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(yourtimestampfield);`. I decided to use this instead of the `int(11)` because of the built in function `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` which shows this format `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Also inside of mysql queries yo may use it the reverse way like `UPDATE user SET logouttime = FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(logintime)+3600) WHERE user_id = 12345;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for help.
But why my TIMESTAMP column do not give a TIMESTAMP ?
In my mind a TIMESTAMP colum give Timestamp, and a DATETIME column give a DATETIME ?!
Very curiuous for me...

Comment: Because a Unix timestamp is different than a SQL database `timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

About TIMESTAMP Data Type:

The `TIMESTAMP` data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of `'1970-01-01 00:00:01'` UTC to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07'` UTC. A TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision.

Example Usage:

```
CREATE TABLE timestamps (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ts1 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  ts2 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  ts3 TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO timestamps VALUES();

+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| id | ts1                 | ts2                 | ts3  |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+
|  1 | 2023-12-22 10:01:46 | 2023-12-22 10:01:46 | NULL |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+

UPDATE timestamps SET ts3 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();

+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | ts1                 | ts2                 | ts3                 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2023-12-22 10:01:46 | 2023-12-22 10:02:57 | 2023-12-22 10:02:57 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

NOTES:

- The `DATETIME` data type is also used for values that contain both date and time parts. The supported values range is `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'` to `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'`.
- If `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is called with no date argument, it returns a **Unix timestamp** representing seconds since `'1970-01-01 00:00:00'` UTC, for example, `1703219968`. And, `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1703219968)` returns `'2023-12-22 10:09:28'`.